# React js unit testing with enzyme

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys i am new to react can anyone help me to write unit test for the below code .. i want to test if link is redirecting properly..

Here is my code ..

```
import React { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import './App.css';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Link to='/college/masters/cs' className="student">  
        <div className="centered">
          <h2 className="Branch">Branch</h2>
        </div>
      </Link>
    );
  }
}
```

My test

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import 'ignore-styles';
import Home from '../src/Home';

describe('<Home/>', function () {
  it('should have a Link', function () {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Home/>);

    expect(wrapper.find('Link')).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

Please help me to write test if link is redirecting properly..

Thank you

Comment: Could you please format the code properly first? It's very hard to read

Comment: sorry for the format can you please help me to write unit test for


<Link to='/college/masters/cs' className="student">


 
i want to test if the link takes to  '/college/masters/cs'

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this out. It should work.
You merely need to check whether you are passing the valid `to` property with a relevant value to the `Link` component. That's it. You don't need to check whether it takes you to the given url, since it is the functionality of the `Link` component and they should have tests to verify that. If you need that then what you are writing is not a unit test, it is called an `e2e`. You may need selenium or so in doing that.

```
expect(wrapper.find('Link').props().to).to.eql('/college/masters/cs')
```